# Query via get com Laravel

Tags: laravel-5.5

Como eu faço para passar dados via get de um formulário? Quando faço o submit, a url fica 
`meusite.com/pesquisar?termo=algumtermo&categoria=algumacategoria` . Como eu passo esses dois parâmetros `termo` e `categoria` para a rota e assim enviar para o controller?

Comment: coloca o código do controller pff, mesmo que não tenha nada para ver como acedes ao `request`

Comment: A rota eu fiz `Route::get('/pesquisar?q={termo}&categoria={categoria}', 'SiteController@pesquisar');` mas se eu acesso essa rota ela não é encontrada. Lá no controller, eu apenas passei `public function pesquisar($termo, $categoria){ return $termo; }`